# Unix: How can I read multiple lines?

Tags: unix, shell

So it seems `read` command only takes 1 line, what if I wanted to input a short paragraph with line breaks? What would I use? I think there's a command that ends when you press ctrl+d, so it return key is used for starting a new paragraph.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
text=$(cat)
```

Allows you to type text with newlines, terminated by a Ctrl-d at the beginning of a line.

The equivalent in Bash, without needing to use an external utility is

```
text=$(</dev/stdin)
```

Comment: +1. Although I much prefer Tobu's suggested method of input, this is more like what OP wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You could drop the user into their favorite editor, with commented text that explains what information is needed and how to make paragraph breaks. That's how most vcs commits work. See ldapvi for a more sophisticated example of this kind of interface.

Comment: This is the smartest of all three. The longer the inputs, more mistakes there are. Launching `$EDITOR` helps a lot, when more than a single phrase is being input.

Answer (score 0):

If line breaks are not essential in the result, you can use '\' character to escape newlines in input.